# Verificar dato de tabla relacionada en Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Saludos y gracias de antemano,

Tengo dos modelos relacionados en Laravel, Productos y FechaProductos

Necesito un query para buscar todos los productos cuyas FechaProductos sean mayor que hoy, de no existir un registro en FechaProductos mayor que hoy, descartaría el producto.

La tabla productos sería:

**id -  nombre - precio** 
1  -  Night -  45  
2  -  Day   -  50

La Tabla FechaProductos sería:

**id -  producto_id - fecha** 
1  -  1      -      2019-11-15 
2  -  1      -      2019-09-05 
3  -  2      -      2019-05-05 
4  -  1      -      2019-04-06

Necesitaría obtener todos los productos con fecha superior a hoy dando como resultado el producto id = 1, suponiendo que hoy es 2019-10-17

Me podéis ayudar?

Gracias!!

Comment: Hola @Francisco puedes colocar lo que tienes desarrollado hasta ahora para poderte ayudar mejor y si te esta generado algo error por favor de colocarlo. Gracias.

Comment: Por favor para poder ayudarte ocupamos lo siguiente: estructura de ambas tablas (es decir que columnas las componen), además que nos muestres por favor lo que llevas hecho, considera leer [ask]

Comment: Listo ya he añadido un pequeño fragmento de la tabla